# Closures and lexical environment in javascript

Tags: javascript

I thought that a closure only was created when a function was called. The [following article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/whats-a-javascript-closure-in-plain-english-please-6a1fc1d2ff1c) (and others) are really confusing me.

> You create a closure whenever you define a function. Then when you
>   execute functions, their closures enable them to access data in their
>   scopes.

Can someone plz clarify if a closure is made when a function is created or when a function is called. Cause I can't seem to find a uniform answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clouser is made when function is created, cause only then you have local variables in your scope that are going into closer.
When function is executed that's the closure in action, you are accessing the variables that went into closure. See the example from the very top on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Answer (score 2):

It is when the function is created. If you create a function inside another, and for example assign it as the event handler to an element, that event handler function must keep a reference to the outer variable scope where it was created, whether or not the handler is ever invoked.

This can only happen if the closure is created upon creation of the function, because the outer function has long since returned but its variables (at least the ones referenced by the handler) must continue to exist in anticipation of the handler's invocation.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function makeAdder(n){
    return function(x){return n+x;};
}

add1=makeAdder(1);
add5=makeAdder(5);
console.log(add1(1));
console.log(add5(1));
console.log(add1(2));
console.log(add5(2));
```

The closure part is that the anonymous function inside "sees" `n`, the argument passed to `makeAdder`. The returned function can be called many times, and it will use the same closure (so the same `n` - it could also change it if it wanted to).

Answer (score 0):

From the simple definition of closure, it is created when a function is created. As its defined as the relationship of a function with the environment within which the function is declared(created).

Answer (score 0):

Closure are created when the function is defined.

Closure simply put is the scope of the function.Any variables declared within the closure of a function isn't available for use outside the closure of that function.
However it is possible for a that particular function to access any items belonging to the closure of another structure as long as this particular function is inside the closure of that structure.

If this doesn't help, try learning about scopes(eg, in Java) closures and scopes are very closely related to each other